# C# Socket sending image results in bad formattted image

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to send an image via a TCP server to a socket.

## Protocol

- first, the server sends a token to the client (encryption is in planning)
- the client receives the token and makes a comparison
- the client reads all bytes from an image into an array
- then the client sends the length of the array to the server
- then the client sends the byte array

But when I write the byte array, received by the client, into a file, it is corrupted, compressed, and likely bad formatted.
Only a few image viewers can display the image and when they can display the image it is compressed and somewhat corrupted.

I know that there are better protocols out there, but for the scope of my project, I want to keep it simple, and therefore I'm using TCP.

## Code

Below is a simplified version of my code.

## Client

```cs
byte[] photo;

string  URL = null;   // simplified
int     Port = 0;     // simplified
string  Token = null; // simplified

using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(URL, Port))
{
    using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
    {
        // send token
        {
            byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Token);
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            stream.Flush();
        }

        // receive incoming byte array length
        Int32 length;
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeof(Int32)];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, sizeof(Int32));
            stream.Flush();
            length = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
        }

        // get image bytes
        photo = new byte[length];
        {
            stream.Read(photo, 0, length);
            stream.Flush();
        }
    }
}



// returns a string representing the path where the image should be stored
string filePath = GetPhotoFilePath(bunker.ID); 

// create directory
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(photoDirectoryPath))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(photoDirectoryPath);
}

// delete file for recreation
if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
}

// create file
System.IO.File.Create(filePath).Close();

// write to file
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, photo);
```

## Server

```cs
int     Port = 0;        // simplified
string  Token = null;    // simplified
string  FilePath = null; // simplified

TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
server.Start();

while (true)
{
using (TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient())
{
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
{
    // Get Token
    string token;
    {
        byte[] token_buffer = new byte[Token.Length]; // use default token length
        stream.Read(token_buffer, 0, token_buffer.Length);
        stream.Flush();
        token = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(token_buffer);
    }

    // if token doesn't match close connection and continue loop
    if (!token.Equals(Token))
    {
        client.Close();
        continue;
    }

    if (!File.Exists(FilePath))
    {
        client.Close();
        continue;
    }

    // read image bytes
    byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);

    // send length of image
    byte[] length = BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length);
    stream.Write(length, 0, length.Length);
    stream.Flush();

    // send image
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    stream.Flush();
}
}
}
```

## Image

### Image from the sender

[image: Original file]

### Image from the reciver

[image: Recived file]

[Edit]
Note, that somehow the image in the preview is only white.
You can open the file in a new tab.

Comment: Look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49718299/tcp-socket-recieves-data-wrong-in-c-sharp

Comment: But im already using TCP

Comment: Do not confuse "low level" with "easy to use". Using a webserver or gRPC will probably be just as easy, but takes care of encryption and many other issues.

Comment: Lacking a [mcve], there's not way to point out _all_ the bugs in your code. But there's one obvious mistake you and every other person reinventing the network I/O serialization wheel seem to make, which is you read from the stream without looking at the number of bytes you actually read. See duplicate.

Comment: yes @PeterDuniho, but I thought, that TCP will automatically request a package if it didn't arrive and check for errors in the packages..

Comment: @JonasH my project is still in its early stage, the encryption is in planning, but now I just want it to run.

Comment: My question is still, why the heck my image is corrupted... I thought TCP takes care of that.

Comment: TCP guarantees only one thing: _if_ you get a byte from the remote endpoint, that byte is correctly ordered relative to all the bytes that were sent before that. You still need to look at the _number_ of bytes that were received, to make sure that you have actually received all the bytes you expected, and to read from the stream again if there are still bytes left to read. For example, you try to read 4 bytes for the stream length, but since you didn't check the count of bytes read, it's possible to get the wrong number, because you use only the first 1, 2, or 3 bytes as the count, ...

Comment: ... instead of all 4 you meant to. Likewise, you attempt to read `length` bytes for the image data, but you are almost _certainly_ not going to get all of the image bytes in one call to `Read()`, and so you don't actually have a complete image. The duplicate, and of course every shred of documentation involving TCP, explains all this in detail.

Comment: @PeterDuniho
Thanks for the explanation, it helped a lot in understanding TCP. You can copy-paste it as an answer in which case I will mark it as accepted.